# Getting a Recursion Error when adding digits to a number

Tags: python, loops, recursion

I'm trying to take a number, check if it's shorter than four digits, and add digits to it if it is. At the end, it will finally return the number to the power of two. It works fine if I only add a positive integer, but I don't want that because all of the numbers it return end with the same number. I tried to have a bit of logic in there, where it takes the first and the last digits of the number and adds it to it each loop, but then it gives me a Recursion Error, because it exceeds maximum recursion depth.

```py
def func(seed):
    length = len(str(seed))
    if length < 4:
        string = str(seed)
        seed = int(string * 2 + '1')  # the '1' can be any positive integer.
        return func(seed)

    return seed ** 2

for i in range(100):
    print(func(i))
```

If I was to replace the `'1'` with `string[0]`, `f'{seed - 2}'`, or even not putting anything there,
 it exceeds the max recursion depth.
I don't understand this, and I was wondering what's going on that it does this. Thanks.

Comment: Excuse me but i didn't understand what are you trying to achieve in the end. It would be great of you to explain what the purpose of the function because it seems like you're adding string to string without doing any calculations to the seed.

Comment: Try printing `seed` each time it's called, to see what;'s happening.

Comment: If you start with "0", then adding string[0] leaves it as a zero and the function doesn't progress.  Do you get the recursion error for starting strings other than "0"?

Comment: @DoronShevach It's the beginning of a pseudo random number generator, I just was having trouble with the recursion.

Comment: You have to ensure that the recursive calls eventually produce a number greater than 999.

Comment: Basic debugging shows what goes wrong. Did you debug at all? Like step through the code, inspect variables?

Comment: @OakenDuck There are many good PRNG algorithms. Don't try to create one without a good understanding of the math.

Comment: I understand it, I just missed the fact that zero will always add onto zero as zero, and never leave the loop

Answer (score 3):

You said:

> the '1' can be any positive integer or zero.

But this is not the case.

Consider if the `seed` value is 0. Then running the function would result in 00 which turns to 0 again when the `int` function is applied resulting in an infinite loop and therefore infinite recursion.

Comment: Yes, thanks. It's funny that I've worked on much harder problems, yet I mess up on little details like this.